# Regarding symbol for cross product

Tags: symbols

May i know the latex syntax for the center symbol (circle with cross)?

[image]

Comment: It's `\otimes` you're looking for.

Comment: Look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol), about how to look up a symbol, in order to use them the next time.